# Creating Oracle OCI plugin for QT Creator

Tags: shell, oracle10g, qt4, oracle-call-interface, instantclient

I am trying to create Oracle OCI plugin for QT creator. The versions of instant client (basic and sdk) are 10.2 for connecting to 10g server.

The directories are as follows-

source files of qt installed in- /home/aj/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4

sdk of qt- home/aj/qtsdk-2009.5

instant client BASIC packages unzipped - /home/aj/Desktop/oracle/instantclient_10_2

instant client SDK packages unzipped - /home/aj/Desktop/oracle/sdk

I used the following steps-

$ cd /home/aj/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/

$ sudo qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/home/aj/Desktop/oracle/sdk/include" "LIBS+=-L/home/aj/Desktop/oracle/instantclient_10_2 -lclntsh" oci.pro

$ sudo make

but the make returned error saying - make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
 any soilutions ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOmetimes during installation it might happen that all the files have not been properly extracted.

Run-> $ sudo make again inside your qt-source directory (in your case  /home/aj/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4)

when it has completed installation & extracting, go to
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.4 and do the following---

```
$sudo cp -rf /home/aj/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/include/QtSql/* ./include/QtSql
$sudo mkdir src
$sudo cp -rf /home/aj/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/src/* ./src/
$sudo cp -rf /home/aj/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4/src/plugins/sqldrivers/oci/libsqloci.so ./plugins/sqldrivers/
```

the file libsqloci.so will be copied in the sqldrivers plugin directory and you are good to go.